# Why is the size of my UIScreen half the size of the iPhone itself(in pixels)?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sprite-kit

So I have been programming in xCode, and I've found out where to position my `SKSpriteNodes` by printing my `UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width/height`. For the iPhone 6, it prints 667 by 375, however the iPhone itself actually is double that, 1334 x 750. Why is this?

Comment: You're seeing points, not pixels. On the iPhone 6, one point = two pixels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because **size in iOS is calculated in points**. Depending on your screen pixel density, either the `scale` is 1, 2, or 3.

Since an iPhone 4 is double the resolution of iPhone 3G but the UI elements must stay the same size, the iPhone 4 is set at a `scale` of 2, so if you make a 50x50 square, **it appears the same size on both devices** even though the true dimensions of the iPhone 4 square is at 100x100.

iPhone 6 uses a scale of 2 and iPhone 6 Plus uses a `scale` of 3. The beauty of this system is that **you don't have to manage the apparent sizes of objects**; if you set the dimensions to 50x50 points, it will stay generally the same size across all devices.